# Input form array value null for some cases

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a big form with almost 13000 inputs(checkboxes), this the html/smarty code, my problem is when checking checkboxes in the end of the form (the last ones), their values got always null.
I debugged the $_POST values like this

```
 if (isset($_POST['partsfilter'])) {
    $vars = $_POST['partsfilter'];
    var_dump($vars[5366]);
    var_dump($vars[5368]);
    var_dump($vars[5525]); this one return null when it shouldn't be 
 }
```

I tried this in htaccess file

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value max_input_vars=15000
```

But always the problem persists
I'm thinking to use AJAX to get values from the checked checkboxes and submit the form, cause the submitted (checked inputs) values are not too much (at least not 13000)

```
  <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmpost">
     <input type="hidden" name="hdn_id_product" value="{$s_product['id_product']}" />
    {foreach from=$make_list item=mark}
    <ul class="acnav__list acnav__list--level1">

        <!-- start group 1 -->
        <li class="has-children">
            <div class="acnav__label ">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4">{$mark.mid} {$mark.name}</div>    
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                 <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="">Compatible</label>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-2">
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                 <label><input type="checkbox" name="front" value="">Front</label>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                               <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label><input type="checkbox"  value="">Rear</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                               <div class="checkbox">
                                 <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Left</label>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Right</label>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>    
                          <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                       Years 
                          </div>    
                       </div>
                                
                                    <!-- add fields -->
            </div>
            <!-- start level 2 -->
            {foreach from=$mark.cc item=cc}
            <ul class="acnav__list acnav__list--level2">
                <li class="has-children">
                    <div class="acnav__label acnav__label--level2">
                        <div style="width: 5%;float: left;opacity: 0.5;">{$cc.ccid}</div> <div style="width: 90%;float: left">{$cc.ccname}</div> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- start level 3 -->
                    <ul class="acnav__list acnav__list--level3">
                        {foreach from=$cc.models item=model}
                        
                        <li>
                                                        
                                                            
                                 <div class="acnav__link acnav__link--level3">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                       <div style="width: 10%;float: left;display: inline-block;">{$model.mid}</div> <div style="width: 30%;float: left;display: inline-block;">{$cc.ccname}</div> <div style="display: inline;width:60%">{$model.name}</div> 
                                                         </div>
                                                     <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                    <label><input type="checkbox" {if isset($results) && isset($results[$model.mid])}{if $results[$model.mid]['compatible'] == '1'}checked{/if}{/if} value="1" name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][comp]" ></label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                    <label><input type="checkbox"  {if isset($results) && isset($results[$model.mid])}{if $results[$model.mid]['front'] == '1'}checked{/if}{/if} name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][front]" value="1"></label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                    <label><input type="checkbox"  {if isset($results) && isset($results[$model.mid])}{if $results[$model.mid]['rear'] == '1'}checked{/if}{/if} name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][rear]" value="1"></label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                    <label><input type="checkbox"  {if isset($results) && isset($results[$model.mid])}{if $results[$model.mid]['l_left'] == '1'}checked{/if}{/if} name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][left]" value="1"></label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>    
                                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                    <label><input type="checkbox"  {if isset($results) && isset($results[$model.mid])}{if $results[$model.mid]['r_right'] == '1'}checked{/if}{/if} name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][right]" value="1"></label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>

                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                        {assign var=thisyear value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"}
                                                                        {if isset($results) && isset($results[$model.mid])}
                                                                        {assign var="years" value=","|explode:$results[$model.mid]['year']}     
                                                                        {else}
                                                                        {assign var="years" value=""}
                                                                        {/if}
                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                            <select name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][yearbegin]" class="col-md-6">
                                                                                {for $foo=1990 to $thisyear}
                                                                                    <option {if  null !== $years AND $years!=""}{if $years[0] == $foo}selected{/if}{/if} value="{$foo}">{$foo}</option>
                                                                                {/for}
                                                                            </select>
                                                                            <select name="partsfilter[{$model.mid}][yearfinish]" class="col-md-6">
                                                                                {for $foo=1990 to $thisyear}
                                                                                    <option {if  null !== $years AND $years!=""}{if $years[1] == $foo}selected{/if}{/if} value="{$foo}">{$foo}</option>
                                                                                {/for}
                                                                            </select>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div> 
                                                                </div>        
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                           
                        </li>
                        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
                                            
                    <!-- end level 3 -->
                </li>

                
            </ul>
            <!-- end level 2 -->
                            {/foreach}
        </li>
        <!-- end group 1 -->

        <!-- start group 2 -->
        
        <!-- end group 2 -->

        <!-- start group 3 -->
        
        <!-- end group 3 -->

    </ul>
    <!-- end level 1 -->
            {/foreach}
            <div class="panel-footer"><button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" name="assign_request"><i class="process-icon-save"></i> Save Information </button></div>

             </form>
```

var_dump($_POST)

```
 array (size=3)
  'hdn_id_product' => string '43' (length=2)
  'partsfilter' => 
    array (size=42)
      5798 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5799 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5806 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5863 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5886 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5872 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6838 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6811 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6820 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5979 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5994 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6001 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6004 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6828 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6081 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6092 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6193 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      4846 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6206 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6224 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6244 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6274 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6338 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6279 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5203 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6327 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6479 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6540 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6542 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6545 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6579 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6649 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6639 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      6650 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5366 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5367 => 
        array (size=3)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
          'rear' => string '1' (length=1)
      5368 => 
        array (size=3)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
          'rear' => string '1' (length=1)
      5369 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5370 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5371 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5372 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
      5373 => 
        array (size=2)
          'comp' => string '1' (length=1)
          'front' => string '1' (length=1)
       'partsfilterYears' => 
    array (size=1457)
      5798 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5799 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5800 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5801 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5802 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5803 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5804 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5805 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5806 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5807 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5808 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5809 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
      5810 => 
        array (size=2)
          'yearbegin' => string '1990' (length=4)
          'yearfinish' => string '1990' (length=4)
```

Comment: Checkboxes don't change their values when you click them. Instead, they change their state (`checked`). To reflect that, only checked checkboxes are sent to the server. So you can check for their existence in the request body data to see if they were checked in the form.

Comment: @shaedrich when a i check a checkbox for example <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="partsfilter['5806'][comp]"> and when i submit the form 
$vars = $_POST['partsfilter']; var_dump($vars[5806]);exit; => i got null

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` output?

Comment: @shaedrich i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

the hosting provider fixed the issue by adjusting this php values

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value max_input_vars=15000
```